# Inclusion exclusion problem, why is my answer nonsense?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

600 residents live in a town. 35% watch show a, 40% watch show b, and 50% watch show c. If 18 percent watch exactly 2 of these shows, and everyone watches at least 1 show, what percentage watches all of the shows.

We are given that 
$$
p(a)=.35\\
p(b)=.4\\
p(c)=.5\\
p(a\cup b \cup c)=1\\
p(a\cap b)+p(a\cap c)+p(c\cap b)=.18
$$
With the last statement probably the source of my error. 
Then by inclusion exclusion we have
$$
p(a\cup b \cup c)=1=p(a)+p(b)+p(c)-.18+p(a\cap b\cap c)\\
\Rightarrow p(a \cap b\cap c)=-.07
$$
Which is nonsense. So why am I wrong, and how would you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be correct if 18% watched at least 2 shows.

But it is 18% watched exactly 2 shows.

So $p(a\cap b)+p(a\cap c)+p(c\cap b) - 3 p(a\cap b \cap c)=.18$

Comment: ah I think I see. thank you.